# Difference between comment line "//" and #region in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, comments

I am a new developer and I am really confused when to use **comment line "//"** and when to use **#region**.

I read an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751229/5143387) about it but my silly brain cant get it through. So, can anyone explain it to me with a piece of code snippet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`//` tells the compiler that from now on, the rest of the line is a comment that is to be ignored. Several of such lines form a group that can be folded (collapsed, such that you do not see any more of it but the first line - try clicking on the little boxed - and + signs in the first line of the comment). Same applies for a block comment (`/* ... */`) and class and function definitions.

`#region` allows you to explicitely define additional folding regions - e. g. if you want to be able to fold big if end else blocks within a function, if you want to group several functions together and fold them as block (e. g. functions for networking, functions for database access, ...).

In the end, you get the same boxed + and - signes for the region you have already for classes, functions, ..., allowing to fold all the code in between the `#region` and the corresponding `#endregion` directives (they always have to be paired!).